# Multipeer connectivity crash attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I am using multi peer connectivity to send files via bluetooth. I found a very strange case that makes the app crash with always the same error:

1) the two devices are connected
2) one of the two disconnects and enters background
3) the other user invites this peer to a session, and the app on this device crashes

In order not to encounter the crash it is necessary to reload the NSNearbybrowser and start browsing again. But when the device goes in background the lost method is not immediately called, and so there is no way to know when to reload. Similar questions have been asked, but I have never seen this error any ware:

[image]

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'
```

Is it my mistake or apple's? If so what should I do?

Comment: Please add Exception Breakpoint in the Xcode's Breakpoints Navigator and show me where it stops.

Comment: unfortunately the line of code where the app stops is not shown

Comment: Do you use dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys: method somewhere in your code?

Comment: Why don´t you post the code that you are using for browsing?

Comment: Somewhere in your app, an `NSDictionary` literal is being used with an object that's `nil`. Place an exception breakpoint to found where, or share your code that's likely to get executed in such a case.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am seeing this in crash reports from my users, but I am unable to recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in reading [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) from Apple (section "Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks") about the ways of keeping a bluetooth communication active even in background mode.

> Support for some types of background execution must be declared in
>   advance by the app that uses them. In Xcode 5 and later, you declare
>   the background modes your app supports from the Capabilities tab of
>   your project settings. Enabling the Background Modes option adds the
>   UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file.

Comment: This is not really answering the question

Comment: well, the question does not provide enough details, probably because you don't have those ones. General crash made me thought about a design problem (bluetooth should be active even if in background mode).

Answer (score 0):

For me I was getting the same crash using the MC Framework, but was not doing Bluetooth.

Instead my problem was that I whenever I was trying to invite from my browser, I was creating the MCPeerID and was not keeping around the original that was given to me during the actual browsing.

Keeping the original MCPeerID object made the app stop crashing for me when I called invite.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Keep a pointer to the original MCPeerID object and don't try to create it, as far as I remember